# NSArrayController: comparison between pointer and integer null

Tags: cocoa, xcode6, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

I'm checking the count of NSArrayController in Xcode console and I get this:

```
(lldb)po [_myArrayAC.content count]
 nil
```

But if I try to check if the value is nil:

```
 if ([_myArrayAC.content count] != nil)
```

I get this error:

```
comparison between pointer and integer null
```

My question is how can I check if my NSArrayController count is null?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is `_myArrayAC == nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSArrayController is of course backed by NSArray
You should ask for the array by the arrangedObjects property.

NSArray is an object so it can be nil. 
nil can receive messages in Objective-C

NSArray has a count property that is an NSUInteger >= 0

You can check to see if the array is nil. 
(No array. A pointer to nil. )

You can check the count. The count always an NSInteger.

Comment: ... so the debugger is producing `nil` because the array is `nil`?  I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Ha. Totally forgot to type that part

Comment: Using the arrangedObjects property will tell you if you have an array at all. It should return a read only NSArray though you set the content property to an NSMutableArray

Comment: arrangedObjects is filtered and sorted content. Why check arrangedObjects?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use the more specific API. That's more likely what you're looking at. if you think the content obj is nil maybe, check that. If you want to see the backing collection object content check it directly and bypass the controller. If it's core data who knows

Comment: Core Data has nothing to do with it. arrangedObjects is the content object, filtered using the filterPredicate and sorted using the sortDescriptors of the array controller.

Comment: from the docs overview: NSArrayController is a bindings compatible class that manages a collection of objects. Typically the collection is an array, however, if the controller manages a relationship of a managed object (see NSManagedObject) the collection may be a set. Hmm. Seems simple. NSSet has same count and nil behaviors described. NSManagedObject is pretty much effectively equivalent in its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

count returns an integer, not a pointer to an object. Instead of po (print object) you should use p (print).
Also an integer can be 0 (zero), not nil or NULL. If you want to check if count is 0 you should compare it to 0.